# Python - KeyError while creating an index

Tags: python, associative-array, keyerror

Here is the code (it runs inside class):

```
if profile['profile_picture']:
    profile['profile_picture_raw_path'], # Line 26
    profile['profile_picture_thumbnail'],
    profile['profile_picture'] = self.picture_path(profile['profile_picture'])
```

Keys don't exist. The typical result returned by `picture_path` is

```
('//domain.com/218971848/21924823397471f5e4e41a803da17f7c.jpg:large', '//domain.com/profile-images/218971848/21924823397471f5e4e41a803da17f7c.jpg:thumb-100', '//domain.com/profile-images/218971848/21924823397471f5e4e41a803da17f7c.jpg:exact')
```

As you can see the result is a tuple of 3 elements.

And I got an error:

```
 File "/srv/rwt/production/application/rwt/profile.py", line 26, in load_profile
    profile['profile_picture_raw_path'],
KeyError: 'profile_picture_raw_path'
```

Why does this error appear? Searched Stack Overflow for similar questions, but they seem to be asked about accessing dictionary values by not-existing keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`profile['profile_picture_raw_path'],` on a line by itself is parsed as a standalone expression (a rather useless one, though).

You need to tell the Python interpreter that the next lines are part of the expression:

```
profile['profile_picture_raw_path'], \
profile['profile_picture_thumbnail'], \
profile['profile_picture'] = self.picture_path(profile['profile_picture'])
```

Comment: Just to mention: you could also parenthize the left hand side of the assignment like `(profile['xxx'],profile['yyy'],profile['zzz'])=...`

Answer (score 1):

use a bracket

```
if profile['profile_picture']:
    (profile['profile_picture_raw_path'], # Line 26
    profile['profile_picture_thumbnail'],
    profile['profile_picture']) = self.picture_path(profile['profile_picture'])
```